# Setting Up Amadeus API On WPGetAPI, Targeted Resource Doesn't Exist?

Tags: wordpress, amadeus

The Project:

We've built a travel booking site and the site needs to include flight booking features.

The Problem:

I'm fairly new to APIs, so beginner's level. We decided to use Amadeus For Developers which provides data for our local flights. We created an app and setup the access token and API Key+Secret. The site is built on WordPress, so we installed a plugin called WPGetAPI, which allows us to easily integrate or make API calls.

However, I keep getting this error each time I try to authenticate:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 38196,
            "title": "Resource not found",
            "detail": "The targeted resource doesn't exist",
            "status": 404
        }
    ]
}
```

and I'm just not sure where I'm getting it wrong. When setting up the access tokens, the most confusing state was the fields, especially that each app uses different terms for the same thing, so I'm not sure what to enter and where (see image below).

[image]

[image]

I basically just tried changing some things on the URLs, etc, nothing much to do. I need precise steps to setup Amadeus on WPGetAPI.

Comment: According to [Amadeus' Common Errors Documentation](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/apis-docs/guides/developer-guides/common-errors/) you're trying to use an endpoint URL that doesn't exist. Without seeing [your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) though that's as far as we can help so edit your question to include more details.